# MySQL INSTR Function or LOCATE Function for find character?

Tags: mysql

I have these string's in row of table in MySQL database:

> XO0071050-MERTINLK
>
> XO6071050-BACKUPS

I need check if the third character of the string is zero and in this case replace the zero with 6.

I have tried without success **MySQL INSTR Function** and **LOCATE Function**.

How to do resolve this?

Can you help me ?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

Comment: could you add the code you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like there should be something better a combination of `LEFT` and `RIGHT` but this should work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(RIGHT(youstring, LENGTH(yourstring) - 2), 1) = 0
            THEN CONCAT(LEFT(yourstring, 2), 6, RIGHT(yourstring, LENGTH(yourstring)-3))
            ELSE yourstring END
  FROM table
```

The `CASE` checks wether the 3 CHAR of your String is a 0 and if it is it replaces it with a 6. It leaves all other 0's how they are

Answer (score 0):

The `INSTR()` and `LOCATE()` functions return the *position* of a substring.  The stated task, however, requires testing the substring (of length 1) at an *already-known* position.  So, `INSTR()` and `LOCATE()` won't help here.

The `SUBSTR()` function (a.k.a. `SUBSTRING()`) *is* useful for that purpose: apply it in a `WHERE` clause test.  For the SET field assignment in your `UPDATE` statement, the `INSERT()` function will do the trick.

The solution is pretty simple, in the end.  Since I fumbled with this sort of problem myself, once upon a time, I'll work through the solution here, concretely and step by step.  Those who are beyond the learning stage of SQL string handling don't need to read further.

Let's say you have table `MyTable` with strings as you describe in column `MyString`, e.g.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM MyTable;
+----+--------------------+
| id | MyString           |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | XO0071050-MERTINLK |
|  2 | XO6071050-BACKUPS  |
|  3 | XO0071050-FOO      |
|  4 | XO6071050-BAR      |
+----+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following then returns the rows that you need to update:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SUBSTR(MyString, 3, 1) = '0';
+----+--------------------+
| id | MyString           |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | XO0071050-MERTINLK |
|  3 | XO0071050-FOO      |
+----+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The three-argument form of the [`SUBSTR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function, as documented along with other available string functions by the nice folks at MySQL on [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html), is `SUBSTR(str, pos, len)`: where *str* is the source string, *pos* is the position (counting from 1) of the desired substring, and *len* is the length of that substring to be returned.  "Length" is in characters, not bytes, and so length of 1 is a single character.

So, the above statement reads through your table of strings, and returns the rows that have the third `MyString` character as `0`.  Since you already know the position of the character in question ("3"), which presumably remains constant, you don't need to resort to any further trickery to get this far.

Now, to arrive at the desired string, use [`INSERT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) to replace that third character with '6'.  (Not to be confused with the `INSERT [INTO] tbl_name` statement type.)  Here's an example in a `SELECT` statement:

```
mysql> SELECT INSERT('XO0071050-FOO', 3, 1, '6') AS 'TestString';
+---------------+
| TestString    |
+---------------+
| XO6071050-FOO |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The four-argument form of this function is `INSERT(str, pos, len, newstr)`... just like `SUBSTR()` except it has a fourth argument *newstr* to specify an "insertion" substring.  The returned string has *newstr* inserted into *str*, substituting the substring beginning at position *pos* and replacing *len* characters.  Above, the substring defined as beginning at position 3 and of length 1, i.e. the first `0`, is replaced with the single-character substring, `6`.

Finally, let's put those both together into an `UPDATE` statement:

```
mysql> UPDATE MyTable
    -> SET MyString = INSERT(MyString, 3, 1, '6')
    -> WHERE SUBSTR(MyString, 3, 1) = '0';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0
```

Rerunning the first two queries above will now give us:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM MyTable;
+----+--------------------+
| id | MyString           |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | XO6071050-MERTINLK |
|  2 | XO6071050-BACKUPS  |
|  3 | XO6071050-FOO      |
|  4 | XO6071050-BAR      |
+----+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And,

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SUBSTR(MyString, 3, 1) = '0';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

There may be a more spiffy solution than this one.  I've tried to keep it simple here, for learning's sake.  And, I've stuck to string functions that have been around since at least MySQL 5.  Those with MySQL 8 and an understanding of regular expressions might instead use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace), especially if the search pattern is more complicated.  Happy queries!